# Viewing source code for a .rb file on a Mac

Tags: ruby

I'm learning how to computer program. I have a Mac running Ruby 1.8.7. When I double click the .rb file to open it and view the source code in Text Wrangler, it looks like gibberish. How do I view the source code?

Comment: .rb files are source code.  Are you sure you're not looking at a compiled file
?

Comment: Thanks for your help. If it's source code, then why does it look like gibberish? How would I know if it's a compiled file? How would I view the uncompiled file?

Comment: Try a different text editor.  Something doesn't seem right here, and there's not enough detail in your question to identify what the problem is.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific as to what *gibberish* means?

Comment: Sure, mu. Lots of code that looks like "ç4ã0è3è3è3è3#4*€ÿ◊€ÿ◊Ÿ÷’€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊€ÿ◊⁄◊÷" etc.

Comment: The code could be in UTF-16, the editor could be misunderstanding the encoding... there could be a lot of reasons. Try `file path/to/rubyfile.rb` and add the result to your question if it comes back with anything conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is not a compiled language, so your .rb file should be source code which can be viewed from the command line or with any plain text editor.  You can open it with the system's TextEdit, with TextWrangler, Sublime Text, Textmate, emacs, vi, pico, nano,...  If you open a Terminal.app (from /Applications/Utilities) and change to the directory containing your source, let's call it `foo.rb`, you should be able to view it by typing `more foo.rb` and pressing the space bar to scroll through it a screen at a time.

If these attempts fail, there are a few possibilities that immediately leap to mind.  1) You got the source from somebody else, and it a) got mangled in transmission; or b) was created on Windows and has DOS line-endings, in which case do a web search for dos2unix. Or 2) you created it with a word processor, such as MS Word or TextEdit in formatted mode, and the program text is interspersed with all of the formatting and layout binary codes.  If you composed it in TextEdit, select `Format -> Make Plain Text` from the menu and then save it.  Anything else, copy and paste to a plain text editor and save it.

Comment: Thanks, pjs. Very thorough. I'm sorry I don't have the reputation points to up-vote you.